# Getting "Ad failed to load : 3" after updating the firebase project

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, admob

In my flutter application, ad is working as expected with test firebase project.
Below is a demo project in which ad is working
https://github.com/jitangupta/flutter-fcm-ads

But when I add my real firebase project I am getting below error

```
I/Ads     (18784): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (18784): Ad with id `0` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
```

Below is a the branch in which ad is not working
https://github.com/jitangupta/flutter-fcm-ads/tree/ad-issue

Below is the commit which holds the actual changes from both branches (main and ad-issue)
[jitangupta/flutter-fcm-ads@1e5ca7d](https://github.com/jitangupta/flutter-fcm-ads/commit/1e5ca7d4514885e24dff6042d8cda96ac5f90294)

Not sure why this is happening.
I debugged the code and found error as "No Ad Config."

Flutter doctor Log

```
PS F:\flutter-fcm-ads> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Flutter run Log

```
PS F:\flutter-fcm-ads> flutter run
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-fcm-ads...                  2,234ms
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
W/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/flutter (17722): Ad with id `0` is not available for onAdImpression.
I/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 5696(630KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(68KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 7223KB/7769KB, paused 34.280ms total 234.856ms
W/flutter_fcm_ad(17722): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
Note: C:\Users\jitan\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-11.2.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\JobIntentService.java uses or 
overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             64.3s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...              1,025ms
W/FlutterJNI(18784): FlutterJNI.setRefreshRateFPS called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(18784): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(18784): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
I/ResourceExtractor(18784): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1641362954770
W/FlutterJNI(18784): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  (18784): uid=10136(com.jugaadhai.app) identical 1 line
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 7690(667KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(184KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2160KB/4320KB, paused 3.291ms total 141.261ms
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for 20.280ms
I/DynamiteModule(18784): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:213806100
I/DynamiteModule(18784): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 213806100
D/DynamitePackage(18784): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
D/DynamitePackage(18784): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(18784): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/WebViewFactory(18784): Loading com.google.android.webview version 74.0.3729.185 (code 373018518)
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...               337ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

 Running with sound null safety 

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:55304/3xqVuKoXM14=/
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(18784): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.leibniz.events.service.START
W/GmsClient(18784): unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.leibniz.events.service.START on com.google.android.gms
I/cr_LibraryLoader(18784): Time to load native libraries: 12 ms (timestamps 6796-6808)
I/chromium(18784): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(50)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_LibraryLoader(18784): Expected native library version number "74.0.3729.185", actual native library version number "74.0.3729.185"
W/cr_ChildProcLH(18784): Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.google.android.webview, sandboxed = true
I/cr_BrowserStartup(18784): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/cr_media(18784): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/Choreographer(18784): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/HostConnection(18784): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xcae44da0, tid 18891
I/FLTFireBGExecutor(18784): Creating background FlutterEngine instance, with args: [--enable-dart-profiling]
D/HostConnection(18784): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglCreateContext: 0xebbd7500: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglMakeCurrent: 0xebbd7500: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcad30790)
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglCreateContext: 0xebbd6300: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglCreateContext: 0xebbd7ec0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/HostConnection(18784): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe2841620, tid 18902
D/HostConnection(18784): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglMakeCurrent: 0xebbd7ec0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc9f2de10)
I/VideoCapabilities(18784): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil(18784): HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 15030(1263KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(140KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 3053KB/4320KB, paused 1.295ms total 254.065ms
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglCreateContext: 0xdf33c2a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf33c2a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcad30790)
E/eglCodecCommon(18784): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
E/eglCodecCommon(18784): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon(18784): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
E/eglCodecCommon(18784): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 0 0
D/DynamitePackage(18784): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads     (18784): This request is sent from a test device.
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/DynamiteModule(18784): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:213806100
I/DynamiteModule(18784): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 213806100
I/GASS    (18784): GassClearcutLogger Initialized.
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Background concurrent copying GC freed 19009(1044KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4465KB/8931KB, paused 4.181ms total 429.283ms
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ProfileSaver for 20.128ms
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for 19.258ms
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/FLTFireMsgService(18784): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!
I/DynamiteModule(18784): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:213806100
I/DynamiteModule(18784): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 213806100
I/GASS    (18784): GassClearcutLogger Initialized.
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 11222(1244KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(240KB) LOS objects, 56% free, 3873KB/8931KB, paused 3.862ms total 462.136ms
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/Ads     (18784): Not retrying to fetch app settings
I/Ads     (18784): Ad failed to load : 3
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglMakeCurrent: 0xebb35a80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcb9e5020)
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9100?uri=http://127.0.0.1:55304/3xqVuKoXM14=/
W/Gralloc3(18784): allocator 3.x is not supported
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglMakeCurrent: 0xebb35a80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcb9e5020)
D/EGL_emulation(18784): eglMakeCurrent: 0xebb2f500: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xebbecf30)
D/eglCodecCommon(18784): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 18247(1455KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3410KB/6821KB, paused 10.265ms total 171.545ms
I/Ads     (18784): This request is sent from a test device.
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.jugaadhai.ap(18784): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/Ads     (18784): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (18784): Ad with id `0` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
```

Answer (score 0):

The second app id looks unusually short, which might explain "No Ad Config.".

```
- "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:773555772554:android:b6a724f81dc3c2680f2173",
+ "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:752358041296:android:dfdede1850ce99fe", // ?!
```

https://github.com/jitangupta/flutter-fcm-ads/commit/1e5ca7d4514885e24dff6042d8cda96ac5f90294